# Windows 10 RTX 2070 using keras gpu with anaconda optimize?

Tags: python, keras, windows-10, anaconda, gpu

I got a new pc recently with a windows 10 and an RTX 2070. I installed anaconda in order to use python and the deep learning frameworks available as keras. I install with anaconda navigator the keras-gpu package. It seems that installing this package will install a "cuda-toolkit 10" and "cudnn" package on anaconda.

I was wondering if my gpu will be used in a optimize way during the training on keras. In fact, in the past, when I installed keras gpu , I had to install microsoft community 2015 and cuda toolkit 9.0/Cudnn on my own in order to make keras gpu working. So, it seems a bit weird that I had no error.

Thank for the help !

Comment: The default logs show output from gpu_device.cc and print the name of the GPU device being used. For ex, this link https://github.com/antoniosehk/keras-tensorflow-windows-installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what backends your keras is using.
e.g. If you are using tensorflow, the following statement will give you the answer.

```
print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())
```